# mysql if elseif syntax condition

Tags: mysql

If I have two parameter "parameterX" and "parameterY"

and I'll using "parameterX" and "parameterY" to commend sql snytax

like as

```
select * from test.test where 
IF(parameterY!=0)
 THEN test.test.'x'=parameterX AND test.test.'y'=parameterY 
ELSE IF
 test.test.'x'=parameterX 
END IF
```

I know this's can't work
But I want to know have a other way like it and it can work in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or easier (than @diehud's answer):

```
select * from test.test where 
test.test.'x'=parameterX AND (test.test.'y'=parameterY OR parameterY=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think dont need use `IF ELSE` syntax

```
select * from test.test where 
(parameterY!=0 and test.test.'x'=parameterX AND test.test.'y'=parameterY)
OR (parameterY = 0 and test.test.'x'=parameterX )
```